# save different array with different length in 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have arrays with different length and I want to save them inside 1D array using python,
a new array is generated after some tests this is why I have different sizes of arrays,
here is a smple of what I have:

```
array1=[1,3,5]
array2=[10,12,13,14]
array3=[12,14,14,15,15] #etc
```

The desired result:

```
myArray=[[1,3,5],[10,12,13,14],[12,14,14,15,15]]
```

I tried to use this code

```
myArray=[]  
myArray.append(array1) 
myArray.append(array2) #etc
```

when I print myArray I get:

```
[[array([1,3,5])], [array([10,12,13,14])], [array([12,14,14,15,15])]]
```

so when I try to get the second array, for example, I have to use this code

```
temp = myArray[1]
result = temp[0]
```

this was working for me but it looks like it has a limitation and it stopped working after a while when I'm retrieving results using some loops.

Comment: If I execute (with Python3) your first block and the code you tried to build `myArray` with (adding a line for `array3`), I get the result you desire.

Comment: In Python, they're called lists, not arrays. It looks like your `array1`, `array2` and `array3` lists are not actually Python lists, but some other type of collection. If they were simple lists, creating your `myArray` list would be as easy as `myArray = [array1, array2, array3]`. Can you show how your "arrays" are being generated?

Comment: Where are these arrays coming from? Can you please show the entirety of your code? The output you shared does not correspond to the your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The currently accepted answer makes little sense, so here's what's actually going on: `array_1`, `array_2`, etc. are not plain Python lists, they're almost certainly NumPy arrays. `my_array`, however, is just a Python list.

Here is a simple program which should allow you to reproduce and understand the difference, at least in how it relates to your program:

```py
import numpy as np

plain_list = [1, 2, 3]

numpy_array = np.array([1, 2, 3])

result_list = [plain_list, numpy_array]

print(plain_list)  # [1, 2, 3]
print(numpy_array)  # [1 2 3]
print(result_list)  # [[1, 2, 3], array([1, 2, 3])]
```

Now, it isn't exactly clear what's happening to your program, since you just write *this was working for me but it looks like it has a limitation and it stopped working after a while when I'm retrieving results using some loops.*

Depending on what the rest of the program is doing, numpy arrays may or may not be the appropriate data structure. In any case, please share the entirety of your code as well as an explanation of the program.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first there is no array data structure in python.
Instead List and tuples are used.
In your case variable `array1`, `array2` & `array3` are lists.

```
array1=[1,3,5]
array2=[10,12,13,14]
array3=[12,14,14,15,15]

# to get the desired result as myArray=[[1,3,5],[10,12,13,14],[12,14,14,15,15]]

myArray = [array1, array2, array3]
```

Check [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) to know more about lists

Comment: If that worked, the `appends` from the question would work as well.

Comment: Yes, it does work with python 3 and python 2.7 as well. i executed in both the versions. 
I provided another way for getting the desired output. maybe question was executed in older version then 2.7

Comment: I'm sure it worked *for you*.  I'm equally sure it wouldn't work for @Emily, or else the original code would have worked as well.

Comment: Totally agreed. 

Comment: To be clear, you agree with @ScottHunter that your post doesn't actually answer OP's question, is that right?

Comment: I agree with @ScottHunter by the way. The OP's question has **nothing** to do with which version of Python it was run on, I don't understand why this was accepted. As they said, your "solution" is identical to the OP's current code, so it's difficult to see the point of this answer.